# Java Swing MVC architecture

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing

How is a Java Swing application organized to achieve MVC architecture?

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979).

Comment: Dang, Google is down again? But seriously, this has been asked and answered many times in many places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See: [A Swing Architecture Overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html)

Answer (score 2):

i would categorize my classes:

- object classes: to represent objects
- functionality classes: to provide functionality. for instance, methods to read/write files or methods to make calculations possibly using some object classes
- and GUI classes (using Swing) which will be what the user will see. these classes will do what the functionality classes provide.

Answer (score 0):

Your project must be consist at least of three entities: your `model`, your `view` and yor `controller`.Your model represents your data, view is a view for your data and controller is something that creates both view and controller.

Let's suppose you've a rectangle and want to build a GUI that shows the area of the rectangle when user types its side.

Your model must extends `Observable` class, in this way you mark class Square as model in your `MCV architecture`.

```
public class Square extends Observable {ecc....}
```

when you set the side, you have to set the state of the model as changed and notify observers which are listening on your model, such as:

```
public void setSide(double side) {
  this.side=side;
  setChanged();
  notifyObservers();
}
```

PS: `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()` are provided by `Observable` class.

Now the second step, your View must implement `Observer` interface, so you mark this as listener for model's change. Implementing Observer forces you to write `update` method.

```
public class Square_View implements Observer {
    JLabel area;
    ......
    @Overried
    public void update (Observable o, Object arg1) {
        Square square=(Square)o;
        area.setText(square.getArea());
    }
```

Well, as soon as your square's side changes, a notification is triggered and update method is invoked.

Now the `controller`, the mind of MVC architecture:

```
public class MyProgram extends JFrame {
      ... somewhere in your class
      Square s=new Square();
      Square_View sv=new Square_View();
      s.addObserver(sv);
}
```

As I said before, you create both model and view and register the view as observer for your model.